# Comprehending which inputs have the highest weight in a neuronal network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am currently working on a Supervised Machine Learning Solution to categorize some data into two classes.
So far I have worked on a keras/tensorflow Python Scipt which seems to manage that just fine:

```
input_dim = len(data.columns) - 1
print(input_dim)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_split=0.33, epochs=1500, batch_size=1000, verbose=1)
```

The input Data I use is a csv data with 168 input features. As I was first running this script successfully I was very surprised to see that I actually got an accuracy of over 99% after only a couple hundred epochs of training. I didn't even bother to normalize the input data yet.

What I am trying to find out now is which of my 168 input features is responsible for such a high accuracy rate and which features dont take much of an effect while training.

Is there a way to check the weights of each input column to see which of them is being used most, respectively which make the most impact.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your last question:

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

However, unless there is an obviously dominating weight, it is unlikely that a single sample gives you good accuracy. For feature selection, try replacing some features of your input by their mean and check how the prediction fluctuates. Little-to-no fluctuation means that the feature is not important.

Also, please consider posting ML questions on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So this would give me the weights right off the input layer from each input feature? Since I have 168 features to start with it would take much time to watch the changings in the accuracy alone for each feature. So I would start with a small number of features with the highest input weight and then start to add more features according to that ranking and see how the accuracy changes... do you think that would work?

Comment: I've seen this method in literature, so why not.

Comment: Okay just to be clear. I have done this and now I have got the 8 weights of every of my 168 input columns. 8 weights, because the next Layer (Layer 1) has a size of 8 and each column has 8 connections to every neuron in that layer. Now you would suggest calculating the mean of those weights for a comparison? Or would it make more sense to add them up?

Comment: The mean of magnitudes or the sum of magnitudes for all weights that are out of the given node -- they are equivalent. It doesn't make a difference in your choice -- to compute mean, you divide each such sum by 8. It doesn't change the relative order. I would also keep an eye on the max of weights for each node...

Answer (score 1):

There is going to be a connection from each 'column' to each neuron in first layer. You could go two ways (apart from randomizing or dropping (equivalent to replacing with mean as suggested in the answer above) the columns values) about finding the relative importance of columns using the weights. Please keep in mind that these methods make sense only if you input standardized dataset

1. You could use `L1` or `L2` norm of each columns weight in the first layer
2. Say your input has 100 columns. You create a layer that dot products the input with a tensor (trainable) of size (100,). Now, you input the output of this layer to your sequential model. Your trained (100,) tensor is the relative importance of your columns

Comment: Could you further explain what the L1 and L2 mean? Are you to the Layers? For the second method you would suggest to place a Layer right after the input Layer with a size equal to my number of inputs? Could you provide a short code example? Thanks